# Is NetworkOnMainThreadException valid for a network call in a coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm putting together a simple demo app in Kotlin for Android that retrieves the title of a webpage with Jsoup. I'm conducting the network call using `Dispatchers.Main` as context.

My understanding of coroutines is that if I call `launch` on the `Dispatchers.Main` it *does* run on the main thread, but suspends the execution so as to not block the thread.

My understanding of `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` is that it exists because network operations are heavy and when run on the main thread will block it.

So my question is, given that a coroutine does not block the thread it is run in, is a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` really valid? Here is some sample code that throws the given Exception at `Jsoup.connect(url).get()`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val job = Job()

    val mainScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)

    // called from onCreate()
    private fun printTitle() {
        mainScope.launch {
            val url ="https://kotlinlang.org"
            val document = Jsoup.connect(url).get()
            Log.d("MainActivity", document.title())
            // ... update UI with title
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can simply run this using the `Dispatchers.IO` context and providing this result to the main/UI thread, but that seems to dodge some of the utility of coroutines.

For reference, I'm using Kotlin 1.3.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> My understanding of coroutines is that if I call launch on the Dispatchers.Main it does run on the main thread, but suspends the execution so as to not block the thread.

The only points where execution is suspended so as to not block the thread is on methods marked as `suspend` - i.e., suspending methods.

As `Jsoup.connect(url).get()` is not a suspending method, it blocks the current thread. As you're using `Dispatchers.Main`, the current thread is the main thread and your network operation runs directly on the main thread, causing the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Blocking work like your `get()` method can be made suspending by wrapping it in `withContext()`, which **is** a suspending method and ensures that the `Dispatchers.Main` is not blocked while the method runs.

```
mainScope.launch {
    val url ="https://kotlinlang.org"
    val document = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        Jsoup.connect(url).get()
    }
    Log.d("MainActivity", document.title())
    // ... update UI with title
}
```

Comment: Even with running this in a suspend function, the result is the same, except the Exception then gets thrown from the `suspend` function: `private suspend fun getDocument(url: String): Document {
        return Jsoup.connect(url).get()
    }`

Comment: You should see a Lint warning saying "Redundant 'suspend' modifier: 
This inspection reports a suspend modifier as redundant if no other suspend functions are called inside." - just because you mark something as suspend doesn't mean it is actually going to suspend - that's what `withContext` is for.

Answer (score 5):

Coroutine suspension is not a feature that magically "unblocks" an existing blocking network call. It is strictly a *cooperative* feature and requires the code to explicitly call `suspendCancellableCoroutine`. Because you're using some pre-existing blocking IO API, the coroutine blocks its calling thread.

To truly leverage the power of suspendable code you must use a non-blocking IO API, one which lets you make a request and supply a callback the API will call when the result is ready. For example:

```
NonBlockingHttp.sendRequest("https://example.org/document",
        onSuccess = { println("Received document $it") },
        onFailure = { Log.e("Failed to fetch the document", it) }
)
```

With this kind of API no thread will be blocked, whether or not you use coroutines. However, compared to blocking API, its usage is quite unwieldy and messy. This is what coroutines help you with: they allow you to continue writing code in exactly the same shape as if it was blocking, only it's not. To get it, you must first write a `suspend fun` that translates the API you have into coroutine suspension:

```
suspend fun fetchDocument(url: String): String = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    NonBlockingHttp.sendRequest(url,
            onSuccess = { cont.resume(it) },
            onFailure = { cont.resumeWithException(it) }
    )
}
```

Now your calling code goes back to this:

```
try {
    val document = fetchDocument("https://example.org/document")
    println("Received document $document")
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.e("Failed to fetch the document", e)
}
```

---

If, instead, you're fine with keeping your blocking network IO, which means you need a dedicated thread for each concurrent network call, then without coroutines you'd have to use something like an async task, Anko's `bg` etc. These approaches also require you to supply callbacks, so coroutines can once again help you to keep the natural programming model. The core coroutines library already comes with all the parts you need:

1. A specialized elastic thread pool that always starts a new thread if all are currently blocked (accessible via `Dispatchers.IO`)
2. The `withContext` primitive, which allows your coroutine to jump from one thread to another and then back

With these tools you can simply write

```
try {
    val document = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        JSoup.connect("https://example.org/document").get()
    }
    println("Received document $it")
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.e("Failed to fetch the document")
}
```

When your coroutine arrives at the JSoup call, it will set the UI thread free and execute this line on a thread in the IO thread pool. When it unblocks and gets the result, the coroutine will jump back to the UI thread.